# $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} \neq 0$ a.e. for $ \nu << \mu$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be $\sigma$ -finite measures and $ \nu << \mu$
  then, show that $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} \neq 0$ a.e [$\nu$].

My attempt : If  $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} = 0$ then for $\nu E = \int_E fd\mu = 0 \forall E$ I am stuck here. I know I need to get a contradiction on absolute continuity of these measure.

Comment: You need to clarify whether the "a.e." refers to $\nu$ or $\mu$...

Comment: Yes. Edited now. Had missed it.

Comment: This is literally trivial. Let $E=\{x:d\nu/d\mu(x)=0\}$. By definition you need to show that $\nu(E)=0$. This is clear because by definition $\nu(E)=\dots$.

Comment: oh yes. Thanks. I just missed it